# how to set flag in windbg

Tags: windbg

Let's say we have 2 functions funcA and funcB, funcA is the upstream of funcB. I want to view certain values and call stack in funcB only if funcA satisfies certain conditions. I can't achieve this through conditional breakpoint in funcB since I don't know how to access the value I want with registers in funcB. The approach I think of it's add conditional break point both in funcA and funcB. In funcA, I set the flag when certain conditions satisfy. In funcB, I check the flag, print certain values if it's set, and reset the flag. But I don't know how to do this in Windbg. Can I define some variables to hold the flag?

Comment: Set a double conditional like .if (funca.x<=>z) {bu funcb} .else{ bc funcb}

Comment: You can use the pseudo-registers (`$t0` through `$t19`) to store how you're accessing things. Their state can be saved with the `.push /r` and `.pop /r` commands if you need to nest for some reason. If you want to use full names or even store a whole expression to evaluate, you can also use aliases which get pasted into your expressions using `${ }` such as `${youraliasname}`. To assign an integer to an alias, you'll need to assign it with `as /x` or you can expand it by assigning to a temporary register. Also, you can use `${/d:youraliasname}` in your expression to see if it has been defined.